# Want to avoid downcasting inside a Strategy passed to a Composite

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

Here is my problem domain in the financial industry :

```
Asset
==========
Asset parent
assetID
+ compareTo(Asset anotherAsset)

Portfolio : Asset
-----------------
name
risk limit
List stocks
+ compareTo(Asset anotherAsset)
+ composite.CompareTo(Portfolio, ComparisonRules).

Stock : Asset
-------
market
amount
company
+ compareTo(Asset anotherAsset)

AnotherStock : Stock
--------------------
someOtherProperty
+ compareTo(Asset anotherAsset)
```

I have applied the composite pattern to structure **Stock**s within **Portfolio**s. I want to have a clean way of customizing the compareTo method of this composite. That is, AnotherStock will always be compared to another AnotherStock, Stocks to Stocks. This looks like the strategy pattern to me.

I would like to do something like the following (psuedocode)

```
differences = composite.CompareTo(anotherComposite, ComparisonRules).

composite.CompareTo would be something like :

ComparisonRules.Compare(this.Stocks[currentAssetID], otherComposite[currentAssetID])
```

ComparisonRules.Compare(Asset a, Asset b) would do something ugly like this :

```
if( a is Stock and b is Stock) : convert to stock and do stock-based comparison
else if (a is AnotherStock and b is AnotherSTock): convert to AnotherStock
```

Is there a way to write ComparisonRules in such a way that I don't have to downcast yet still provide a custom ComparisonRules object?

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear; what is `composite.CompareTo`? Assuming you're providing a class diagram (of sorts) at the start of your question, the naming of `composite.CompareTo` is invalid. Also "customizing the `compareTo` method of this composite" is not entirely clear; do you mean you want to be able to provide a list of rules, and that each rule must deal either with `AnotherStock`, `Stock`, etc.?

Comment: >do you mean you want to be able to provide a list of rules, and that each rule must deal either with AnotherStock, Stock, : Yes

Comment: Does a comparison rule operate on two stocks (i.e. comparing one stock to another) or on two lists of stocks (comparing one list to another)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a rule perspective, it sounds like what you need are generics. If you define something along these lines:

```
public class ComparisonRule<TStock> where TStock : Stock
{
    public int Compare(TStock lValue, TStock rValue)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

That will guarantee that only types at or below `TStock` will be accepted. For example, if I had a `ComparisonRule<AnotherStock>`, then only types at or below `AnotherStock` could be passed in. However, you may want to rethink your type hierarchy if you want to be able to define a rule that can compare `Stock` but not `AnotherStock`. You should consider having a common ancestor, but the concrete stock types should be in different inheritance trees.

In other words, you have this:

```
              Stock
                |
    --------------------------
   |                          |
OneStock                AnotherStock
```

This would allow you to define a rule that could compare any `Stock` as `ComparisonRule<Stock>`, or a rule that can only compare `OneStock` as `ComparisonRule<OneStock>`.

This, however, doesn't help you sort out how to know which `Stock` objects to pass to which rules at a higher level. For that, you'll need to be able to define a less-specific version of `ComparisonRule` We can do that with an interface:

```
public interface IComparisonRule
{
    bool CanCompare(Stock lValue, Stock rValue);
    int Compare(Stock lValue, Stock rValue);
}

public abstract class ComparisonRule<TStock> : IComparisonRule where TStock : Stock
{
    bool IComparisonRule.CanCompare(Stock lValue, Stock rValue)
    {
        return lValue is TStock && rValue is TStock;
    }

    int IComparisonRule.Compare(Stock lValue, Stock rValue)
    {
        return Compare((TStock)lValue, (TStock)rValue);
    }

    public abstract int Compare(TStock lValue, TStock rValue);
}
```

Now, strictly speaking, your question asked how to do this without downcasting, which (again, strictly speaking) isn't possible. This, however, should save you from having to do that with every implementation. For example, a simple rule to compare two `AnotherStock` instances would be:

```
public class MyRule : ComparisonRule<AnotherStock>
{
    public override int Compare(AnotherStock lValue, AnotherStock rValue)
    {
        return lValue.someOtherProperty.CompareTo(rValue.someOtherProperty);
    }
}
```

At the higher level (i.e. within `Portfolio`), you can simply hold on to a list of `IComparisonRule` as your rules, then you can call `CanCompare` and pass in two `Stock` instances to see if it's a valid comparison, then pass them into `Compare` in order to perform the comparison.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer.